# Import external GPS Data into Django Project

Tags: python, django, gps

I'm working on my first Django app at the moment trying to display GPS Data on a GoogleMap. So far I have everything running with static points on the map. I now have an GPS module that sends messages every 5 seconds to my computer and I now need to figure out how to import the data into my current project.

At the moment I just have a basic Python file running picking up the data and displaying it in the shell which is working fine.

```
import socket
import sys,os //probably not needed at the moment

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.33.177", 60043))
while 1:
    (received,from_) = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print from_
    print received
```

Now how do I get this to be stored in my Django app? I guess I have to add something to the models file for the data, but I don't know where I need to put the part from below asking for the received data and actually storing it in the database.

I would be thankful for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating standalone python programm

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket, string
import MySQLdb
import select

def write_message(x):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="****", db="****", charset='utf8')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = '''INSERT INTO test(test_c) VALUES ('%(test_c)s') '''%{"test_c":x}
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return x  

HOST = ""
PORT = 1234567

srv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
srv.bind((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
    print u"Listen to " + str(PORT)
    srv.listen(1)             
    sock, addr = srv.accept()
    while 1:
        pal = sock.recv(2048)
        if not pal: 
            break
        print u"Recieved %s:%s:" % addr, pal
        lap = write_message(pal)
    sock.close()
```